# How many times would a $45$ minute event have occurred per $60$ minutes?

Tags: calculus

I have two types of events. Event $A$ occurs every $45$ minutes, and Event $B$ occurs every $60$ minutes. I would like a way to calculate how many times Event $A$ will have occurred at any given occurrence of Event $B$.

It's not as simple as $\frac43$ of the input for inputs that aren't multiples of $3$. (ie: When Event $B$ occurs $2$ times, Event $A$ has also only occurred $2$ times). Only integer inputs are valid.

I'm guessing it will involve calculus, but I'm really stumped on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 'floor' function. Let B be the number of times the 60 minute event has occured and A be the number of times the 45 minute event has occured , then

$$A = \lfloor \frac{60B}{45} \rfloor = \lfloor\frac{4 B}{3} \rfloor $$

The floor function gives the greatest integer less than or equal to a given value , for positive examples , f(1.98) =1 , f(5) = 5 , or more simply , it just takes the integer part.

Comment: I feel very stupid for not thinking of this. I guess I'm pretty rusty. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. :)